# How to install zutils on Centos7

Tags: centos

How do I install zutils on CentOS7?  I want to use the zutils version of zgrep.

I tried yum install zutils but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Zgrep is available on Centos 7 and doesn't need to install.Also for zcat and zcmp. You don't need to install zutils.But the install from rpm command after download it with

## RPM -ivh /Package name

could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any zutils RPM for CentOS and [rpmfind](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=zutils) doesn't list any.  So you may need to compile and install it yourself.

NOTE: You need to be careful about replacing OS binaries with third party ones.

To start with, the `gzip` package is a core dependency in CentOS 7.  If you overwrite `/usr/bin/zgrep` with the `zutils` version then you'll probably find it gets switched back to the `gzip` version whenever there's an update of the `gzip` package.

So if you do want to use `zutils` then you'll need to make sure it's elsewhere on the machine (eg in `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/bin`) and `PATH` points to that.